# Какое минимальное четырехразрядное число в двоичной системе счисления?

Tags: системы-счисления

Вопрос из школьного курса по инфе.

Какое минимальное четырехразрядное число в двоичной системе счисления (в старшем разряде не может стоять 0, указывать основание счисления в ответе не нужно)?

Comment: Эм, 1000? Причём в ЛЮБОЙ системе счисления

Comment: @andreymal кроме унарной )

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, число, начинающееся с 1 и состоящее из 4 разрядов: `1000`